# How to anchor controls in WPF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, anchor

I have a a `TreeView` that fills the top part of the application, but since the number of items in the `TreeView` changes, my Apply button changes its position vertically. Is there a way to anchor it to the bottom part of the window, so it's always on the right bottom part of the window, i.e. 10x10 distance from the right bottom edge.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can either set the HorizontalAlignment and VerticalAlignment on the TreeView or Button (I cannot tell which control you are trying to anchor), or you could place the control inside a DockPanel.

To space the control away from others use the Margin.

```
Margin="0 0 10 10"
```

will give you the margin only on the right and bottom

I hope this makes it a bit clearer:

```
<Window>   
  <DockPanel VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <TreeView DockPanel.Dock="Top" />
    <Button DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Margin="0 0 10 10" />   
  </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to anchor the button the window.

Comment: Thanks, but when I do that it anchors to TreeView, not the Window.

Comment: Thanks, btw can I use the DockPanel, inside a Grid tag? So Window -> Grid -> DockPanel. Or should I get rid of it?

Comment: Almost anything is possible, in my current project I have Grid > Grid > Items Control > StackPanel as ItemsPresenter > Grid for each item

Answer (score 41):

To achieve anchoring, Set following properties:

- Width="auto"
- Height="auto"
- VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
- HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
- Set margins as needed.

Example:

```
    <TabControl

        Name="tabControl1"

        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 

        Margin="40,40,40,40"  

        Width="auto" 

        Height="auto" 

        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
```

Comment: This answer is definitely the best one for achieving something closer to the classic WinForms "anchor" property.

Answer (score 7):

I think you need this in the XAML of your button:

```
HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
```

Comment: Thanks but how I am gonna specify the spacing?

Comment: @Joan Venge With the Margin property I guess.

Comment: I can't get this to work. When I make the window bigger the stuff aligned to the bottom is not at the bottom anymore. Is there a property for: "No Really, I want this at the bottom of the window"