# how to set the position of usercontrol and change it programmatically in wpf C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

Hello i created a large usercontrol and create the panal on the main windows of wpf i add the usercontrol to the panel but when i try to set the position of if i cant use `usercontrol.Left`or `usercontrol.Top` like winform so what is the way to make like that in wpf
here what i did :

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    slidebtn sld = new slidebtn();

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        stk.Children.Add(sld);


    }

    private void nxt_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    { 
        sld.Left            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 choice to change user control position.

1. Margin

   `sld.Margin = new Thickness(200, 30, 0, 0);`
2. Render Transform

   `var tt = new TranslateTransform();
   sld.RenderTransform = tt;
   tt.X = 200;
   tt.Y = 30;`

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try setting `HorizontalAlignment` and `VerticalAlignment`of your `usercontrol` to anchor it on a position according to your need and with proper margins.

Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188586/how-to-anchor-controls-in-wpf) for more.

Comment: and if i want to create a button change the position of usercontrol how can i do it ?

Comment: You change the appropriate property from C# like `sld.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left;`