# How to stop my WPF element from moving after it reaches its MaxWidth

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a WPF element in my appliation that is supposed to stay on the left side of the screen, Like a menu for example.

When the app is resized or in full-screen I want the element to stretch a little bit, Which it does, but it stretches too much.
I put a MaxWidth on it, thinking it would solve my problems. However when the element reaches its MaxWidth it starts going to the right.

Could you help me with that ?

Comment: Please provide your XAML markup. We need a [mcve] to answer your question. Please also consider reading [ask] a good question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5188586/how-to-anchor-controls-in-wpf
check this out.

Comment: please provide your XAML Code